# Starting with Android 14, users can close foreground notifications

Tags: android

I don't understand this policy. The foreground service is obligated to notify the user and indicates that it is eating up resources, but even after closing the notification, the foreground service is still running. How do I solve this?

Should I force the notification to come back as soon as the user closes it by adding a dismiss intent? I want the user to constantly see notifications.

---

in MyService.kt

startForeground(ID, notification)